# CentOS 8 に mariadb 10.5 をインストールしたい

Tags: centos, mariadb

CentOS 8.2に以下のコマンドでmariadbをインストールすると、その下にある様にmariadb 10.3がインストールされる様ですが、最新版である10.5をインストールする為にはどうすべきなのでしょうか？初めから10.5をインストールできるのか、あるいは10.3からアップグレードしなければならないのか、両ケースにつき、それぞれのコマンドをお教え願いませんでしょうか？

```
yum -y install mariadb-server
```

mariadbバージョン：
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

環境：
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Installing MariaDB Server 10.5.5 on CentOS 8](https://blog.dbi-services.com/installing-mariadb-server-10-5-5-on-centos-8/), [Install MariaDB Server 10.5 on CentOS 8](https://www.centlinux.com/2020/05/install-mariadb-server-105-on-centos-8.html), [upgrade mariadb 10.3.3 to 10.5.5, Please guide me the steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63879641/9014308)

Comment: kunif 様、関連の情報をどうしても探すことができずにおりました。ご提供頂きまして感謝いたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS8 の標準リポジトリに用意されている MariaDB ですが、現時点では 10.3 までのようです。

最新版 (10.5) を利用したい場合には、ソースコードからのコンパイル、または別のリポジトリからのインストールが必要になります。

MariaDB に関しては公式が各ディストリビューション向けのパッケージとリポジトリを用意しているようなので、こちらを利用するのが一番簡単そうです。

なお、余談ですが CentOS 8 から `yum` の代わりに `dnf` コマンドでパッケージを管理するようになっています。 yum もしばらくは使えますが将来的に廃止になるので、早いうちに慣れておくことをおすすめします。
(基本的にはコマンド名を置き換えるだけでほぼ今までと同じように使えます)

---

**手順:**

MariaDBのリポジトリを追加

```
$ sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo<<EOF
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.5/centos8-amd64
module_hotfixes=1
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
EOF
```

MariaDB-server パッケージをインストール

```
$ sudo dnf install MariaDB-server
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

**参考:**

[Download MariaDB Server - MariaDB.org](https://mariadb.org/download/#mariadb-repositories)
[Install MariaDB 10.5 on CentOS 8 | CentOS 7 | ComputingForGeeks](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-mariadb-on-centos-7-centos-8/)

Comment: cubick様、ご教授頂き、また参考リンクをご提供頂きまして、感謝の限りでございます。

Comment: 上記の記述により、10.5のインストールができるだけでなく、当方の環境では10.3から10.5へのアップグレードもできる様でございます。